# 3 background images, each taking 1/3 of banner, how to crop each's width responsively while fixing height

Tags: html, css, reactjs, image, react-bootstrap

Sorry in advance if this is a silly question; I'm not too great with CSS.

I'm working on react-bootstrap code that defines an image banner with three images that each take up 1/3 of the width:

```
var bannerStyle = {
    backgroundImage: `url(${picture1}), url(${picture2}), url(${picture3})`,
    backgroundSize: "33.333333%",
    backgroundPosition: "top left, top center, top right",
};
return (
    <div className="inner-banner text-center" style={bannerStyle}>
        <div className="container">
            <div className="box"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

[image]

As you can see, the three display their full width, even if that results in their heights being mismatched and not taking up the full height of the banner. This effect becomes worse as the window is resized. I want to, instead, make these images all occupy the *fixed height* of the banner div, and maintain their 1/3 of `backgroundSize` by dynamically *cropping their width* - ideally while keeping them centred.

I've been looking around for how to do this, but can't find something that addresses this specific use case. Is there a way to accomplish this using the `backgroundImage` method or will I have to re-implement this?

Comment: try `backgroundSize: "33.333333% 100%"`

Comment: @TemaniAfif that squishes the images; I want to crop their width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a grid. For it to work, you need to wrap the three images in a container, which would be your banner. This container than needs the following css:

```
.banner-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
```

So you don't need the property backgroundSize anymore, as the `grid-template-columns` define that every child should get 1 **fr**action of the parents width. In your case 100 / 3 = 33,33.

EDIT:
Here is an example with jsx code. I put the pictures in an array (obviously, they're all null now, you have to replace picture with the real value) and map over it. Around all I wrap a container which acts as the parent and needs the grid styles:

```
import React from "react";

export default () => {
  const pictures = [picture1, picture2, picture3];
  const bannerContainer = {
    width: "100%",
    display: "grid",
    gridTemplateColumns: "1fr 1fr 1fr",
    gridTemplateRows: "1fr"
  };

  return (
    <div className="banner-container" style={bannerContainer}>
      {pictures.map(picture => (
        <div
          className="inner-banner text-center"
          style={{
            backgroundImage: `url(${picture})`,
            backgroundPosition: "top left, top center, top right"
          }}>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="box"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I created this [pen](https://codepen.io/Gh05d/pen/NWGoyWa) for you to play around.

Comment: thanks for the response, but I couldn't get your answer working in my code. could you maybe edit it so I can see how everything fits together in the JSX syntax? I'm not sure I'm clear on which styling goes on which divs

Answer (score 0):

You will need to separate the backgrounds. You can try adding pseudo element so you don't add more code:

```css
.box {
  height:300px;
  position:relative;
  padding:0 33.4%;
  background:url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/1002/800/800.jpg) center/cover content-box;
}
.box:before,
.box:after{
   content:"";
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   width:33.3%;
   background:center/cover;
}
.box:before {
  left:0;
  background-image:url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/1074/800/800.jpg);
}

.box:after {
  right:0;
  background-image:url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/108/800/800.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Like below in case you want to define the image inline:

```css
.box {
  height:300px;
  position:relative;
  padding:0 33.4%;
  background: center/cover content-box;
}
.box:before,
.box:after{
   content:"";
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   width:33.3%;
   background-position:center;
   background-image:inherit;
}
.box:before {
  left:0;
   background-size:0 0,cover;
}

.box:after {
  right:0;
   background-size:0 0,0 0,cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="background-image:url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/1002/800/800.jpg),url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/1074/800/800.jpg),url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/108/800/800.jpg)">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a grid containing image elements as suggested by @Gh05d. This is the full code that made it work:

```
var bannerStyle = {
    height: '300px',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    display: 'grid',
    gridTemplateColumns: '1fr 1fr 1fr',
    gridTemplateRows: '1fr'
}
var imageStyle = {
    height: '100%',
    width: 'auto',
    minWidth: window.innerWidth / 3 + 'px',
    objectFit: "cover"
}
return (
        <div className="inner-banner text-center" style={bannerStyle}>
            <img src={picture1} alt="" style={imageStyle} />
            <img src={picture2} alt="" style={imageStyle} />
            <img src={picture3} alt="" style={imageStyle} />
        </div>
);
```